# Web Scraping Using Selenium to get date based data

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm very much new to Web Scraping, I really emphasize on new.
I need to scrape data from a table on a website. That table changes every day (stock prices). until now my code extracts the data for one single day, but I need it to do for multiple days at once. The web page has a calendar, you can choose a day and it shows you its history.
I'm using selenium.
Here's part of my code to show you what I'm doing`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options



chrome_path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("headless") 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path , options = chrome_options , keep_alive = False) 
driver.get("http://www.casablanca-bourse.com/bourseweb/indice-ponderation.aspx?Cat=22&IdLink=298")


codelist = []
instrumentList = []
NbreList = []
CoursList = []
FacteurList = []
FacteurPlafList = []
Capitalist = []
poidList = []

for i in range(4,77):
    codepath = f"""//*[@id="Ponderation1_UpdatePanel1"]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]"""
    code = driver.find_element_by_xpath(codepath)
    codelist.append(code.text)
```

Comment: I dont think your above code will be able to scrape data even for one date. Based on your above your list -**codelist**  will contains nothing first value of **Code Isin** column 73 times ( As you are looping 73 times) which is **MA0000011488** for default date 18/08/20

Comment: It's just part of the code. The list has other items and it's perfectly working. I zipped the elements in the list

Comment: It's probably because I forgot to add the {i} to tr

Answer (score 0):

Change the date and click the button

```
driver.find_element_by_id("Ponderation1_DateTimeControl1_TBCalendar").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("Ponderation1_DateTimeControl1_TBCalendar").send_keys("19/08/2020")
driver.find_element_by_id("Ponderation1_ImageButton1").click()

for i in range(4,77):
    codepath = f"""//*[@id="Ponderation1_UpdatePanel1"]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/table/tbody/tr[{i}]/td[2]"""
    code = driver.find_element_by_xpath(codepath)
    codelist.append(code.text)
    
print(codelist)
```

Also put `{i}` for the tr

Answer (score 0):

As you have defined one list for each column. I assume you want to store data of each column in a separate list and you want to load table based on date. You can define below function and then call your function to get data for each column.

```
def scraping_table (date, columnNumber):
    colList =[]
    colXpath = "//tr[td[text()='Code Isin']]//following-sibling::tr//td["+str(columnNumber)+"]"

    #Enter date in date picker
    datePicker = driver.find_element_by_name("Ponderation1$DateTimeControl1$TBCalendar")
    datePicker.clear()
    datePicker.send_keys(date)
    driver.find_element_by_name("Ponderation1$ImageButton1").click()
    time.sleep(6) #Wait for table to laod
    data = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(colXpath)
    if len(data) >2: # If table is empty for a date no record will be returned
        for i in range (2, len(data)-1):
            colList.append(data[i].text)
    return colList



chrome_path = '..\drivers\chromedriver'
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path , options = chrome_options , keep_alive = False)
driver.get("http://www.casablanca-bourse.com/bourseweb/indice-ponderation.aspx?Cat=22&IdLink=298")

# Call function Now, Can pass date and column as per your need

codelist = scraping_table('17/08/2020', 2) # Note your table has hidden columns and Code Isin is column number 2
instrumentList = scraping_table('17/08/2020', 3)
NbreList = scraping_table('17/08/2020', 4)
CoursList = scraping_table('17/08/2020', 5)
FacteurList = scraping_table('17/08/2020', 6)
FacteurPlafList = scraping_table('17/08/2020', 7)
Capitalist = scraping_table('17/08/2020', 8)
poidList = scraping_table('17/08/2020', 9)

# To illustrate i have printed values of 'Nombre de titres' column

for num in NbreList:
    print(num)
```